# How to switch pages in api?

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, pagination, tableview

I have an API, which has to be implemented in a table view. The `API` has multiple pages. What method should I implement so that as the tableview reload's I get data from next page and so on.

Note: the api is in `json`, in which there is an array with dictionaries as it's elements :-

> page =1 [{key: value, key: value, key: value}, {key: value, key:
>   value, key: value}, {key: value, key: value, key: value}, .....}]
>
> page =2 [{key: value, key: value, key: value}, {key: value, key:
>   value, key: value}, {key: value, key: value, key: value}, .....}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say exactly since the json you've posted isn't valid, but assuming 'page=1' is a key with the value being the data for that page, it should be pretty straight forward:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger currentPage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *json;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *pageData;

 - (NSArray *)pageData {
    return [self.json objectForKey:@(self.currentPage)];
}
```

Then you just need to make sure to adjust currentPage value when the page changes, and that your table uses pageData for its data.

Answer (score 0):

you can maintain a global integer (set default 0) then store current page number in it and can increment by 1 every time you reload a table.

Hope below code will give some idea.

```
func btnReloadAction{
tblMain.reload()
intCurrentPage += 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return mainArray[intCurrentPage].count
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let aTitle : String = mainArray[intCurrentPage][indexpath.row]["key"]
}
```